# How and from whom did Duryodhana learn the art of Jalastamba (art of staying under water)?

Tags: mahabharata, duryodhana

In the 18th day of Kurukshetra, Duryodhana hid himself inside the water using a knowledge he had about staying under water. There is no way Drona might have taught him this technique since Drona considered Arjun as his favorite student. There is no reason for Drona to teach this technique only to Duryodhana. In Ghosh Yatra Parva, when Duryodhana was sitting sad after Pandavas came to his resuce from Gandarvas, some Asuras kidnapped him and assured to help him during the war. Still there is no reference of Asuras teaching him this technique. So exactly where and from whom Duryodhana learnt the technique of staying under water? This is a [quote](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09030.htm) from Shalya Parva where Duryodhana hid under water:

> king Yudhishthira the just, O monarch, arrived at the lake known by the name of Dvaipayana within which Duryodhana then was. Wide as the ocean itself, its aspect was agreeable and its waters were cool and transparent. Solidifying the waters by means of his power of illusion, by, indeed, a wonderful method, thy son Duryodhana, O Bharata, happened to be within that lake. Indeed, within those waters lay, O lord, that king, armed with his mace, who, O ruler of men, could not be vanquished by any man! Staying within the waters of that lake, king Duryodhana heard that tumultuous noise (of the Pandava army) which resembled the very roar of the clouds

Comment: Jalastamba is taught by durvasha Rishi.. on being happily satsified by duryodhanas benevolence not only that he had mantras to stop devatas Indra, Varu, Agni, Prithvi and Vayu. there around 3000 mantras he had mastered from durvaasa Rishi. why he hide into water is by power of this mantras he taught he would be able awake all his brother who are killed.